# How to download a video from tiktok cdn on button click with NextJS 13 (app) without getting cors error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, download, cors

So I am making a Tiktok downloader that downloads a Tiktok video. I already have an API that gets the URL of the video.

Here is the sample link
[A video from tiktok](https://v39-dynamic-ceb1a.tiktokcdn.com/4b8b52de8905d9e8ec91e81ac5aa54f7/650d7dea/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037/o81KAghoZBJxLAomBOvT3VwIzNAgfAQCpAFyGE/?a=1180&ch=0&cr=0&dr=0&lr=all&cd=0%7C0%7C0%7C0&cv=1&br=782&bt=391&bti=OHYpOTY0Zik7OzlmOm01MzE6ZC4xMDo%3D&cs=0&ds=3&ft=7b3-cDIENA7VQHgGYAuTLd.olY2p8lcywfuwyWHrK&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=OWU2ZGZoZGU7OmRoZTw6PEBpajU5bTM6ZjxnbjMzODgzNEAwY2EvLi9jNS4xX2IyMzYvYSNuZmcxcjRnYy1gLS1kLy1zcw%3D%3D&l=202309220543147927725C85E05423B21D&btag=e00088000)

This is my code for downloading the file

```
  const downloadFile = async (fileUrl: string) => {
    try {
      const data = await axios
        .get(fileUrl, {
          responseType: "blob",
        })
        .then((response) => {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute("download", "file.mp4");
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
        });


    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

However I am getting this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://v39-dynamic-ceb1a.tiktokcdn.com/4b8b52de8905d9e8ec91e81ac5aa54f7/650d7dea/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037/o81KAghoZBJxLAomBOvT3VwIzNAgfAQCpAFyGE/?a=1180&ch=0&cr=0&dr=0&lr=all&cd=0%7C0%7C0%7C0&cv=1&br=782&bt=391&bti=OHYpOTY0Zik7OzlmOm01MzE6ZC4xMDo%3D&cs=0&ds=3&ft=7b3-cDIENA7VQHgGYAuTLd.olY2p8lcywfuwyWHrK&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=OWU2ZGZoZGU7OmRoZTw6PEBpajU5bTM6ZjxnbjMzODgzNEAwY2EvLi9jNS4xX2IyMzYvYSNuZmcxcjRnYy1gLS1kLy1zcw%3D%3D&l=202309220543147927725C85E05423B21D&btag=e00088000' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried adding withCredentials=true and withCredentials=false, but I still failed.

Comment: We built CORS into the browser to provide apps like tik tok with some protection from unauthorized data access like you're trying to do. This is web scraping, not an API.

Comment: @JBallin Ooooh, I'm trying to do clone of tiktok downloader websites, I'm wondering how are they able to do it without getting cors errors

Comment: These websites are openly violating the TOS by hacking around their security. Is someone telling you that is legitimate software engineering?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was just experimenting with this side project of mine. I think I'm gonna have to dump this project now, i thought it was legal

Comment: It's all good! I'm just seeing a lot of these kind of questions come up recently so I'm curious what the source of it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get access to videos legitimately from TikTok is to use their Research API: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/about-research-api/

Other than that CORS is there for a reason.